# How to obtain the number of digits in n!?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

How to obtain the number of digits in $n!$ ?

My approach :

I Used Stirling's formula to find out the approximate value of  $n!$

Let the approximate value be $S$

Thus, number of digits in $\ =  \left \lfloor \log S \right \rfloor$ + 1

where $\left \lfloor . \right \rfloor$ is floor function.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113167/can-one-know-how-large-a-factorial-would-be-before-calculating-it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question came up [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170/how-good-is-kamenetskys-formula-for-the-number-of-digits-in-n-factorial) on MathOverflow.

Comment: Great! What a coincidence!

Answer (score 3):

Number of digits in $n!=1+$ $\left \lfloor \log(n!) \right \rfloor$. Now $\log(n!)=\log(1)+\log(2)+...+\log(n)$. Therefore, Number of digits in $n!=$ $1+ \left \lfloor \sum_{1}^{n}\log(k)  \right \rfloor$.